# Jmeter Clear cookies after each http request

Tags: jmeter

In jmeter context, is there any way to clear cookies after each http request within the same thread group?

Comment: Like you say, it's for each iteration, not for each http request sampler within the  loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why in that case you need HTTP Cookie Manager at all? Just remove it and you'll get expected behaviour.

Just in case you have some form of weird negative test scenario:

1. Add a [Beanshell Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener) or [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) at the same level with all HTTP Request samplers
2. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;

   CookieManager manager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getProperty("HTTPSampler.cookie_manager").getObjectValue();
   manager.clear();
   ```

See the following reference material:

- [JMeterContext class JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) (referenced as `ctx` in the above script)
- [CookieManager class JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/control/CookieManager.html)
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

Comment: I tried the same code in JMeter 5.2.6 Bean shell sampler and listener..it is throwing me an error..

Comment: Make sure to have [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) added to your Test Plan and the Sampler needs to be in the HTTP Cookie Manager's [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/). Also [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)