# JMeter clear cookie after HTTP Request in same iteration

Tags: cookies, jmeter, iteration

I am struggling with the cookies to clear after certain step. This is what I have in a sample test plan

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bWr6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCeaz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhS3b.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmaY5.png)

I am getting a data from CSV file and then I have multiple cookies - which are location IDs which I need to pass for each row from CSV. I have tried using the Cookie Manager with option to clear iteration which works fine for next row from CSV but not to loop through cookie list defined in the user defined variable. I looked at this **[article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640234/jmeter-clear-cookies-after-each-http-request)**
I have tried adding this code at the same level as the HTTP request but get an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`sampler.getCookieManager().clear()` function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#getCookieManager--) should do the trick for you

Demo:

[image]

Given you're getting an [NPE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) most probably something is wrong with your HTTP Cookie Manager configuration, you can try [enabling debug logging for it](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) to see if JMeter "complains" on anything and if it does - fix the HTTP Cookie Manager configuration accordingly.

In order to get extended debug information for the HTTP Cookie Manager add the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager" level="debug" />
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

Comment: Hi @Dmitri i tried with this assertion code def manager = sampler.getCookieManager()
log.info('Before :  # of cookes was' + manager.getCookies().size())
manager.clear()
log.info('After :  # of cookes was' + manager.getCookies().size())   see this image https://imgur.com/a/5oh4umZ  i am still getting this error *javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getCookies() on null object*

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for the answer it was quite simple in my case. I just had to add the blank Cookie Manager

[Header Cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvXHS.png)

Earlier I had these filled with the values which was causing some issues.
Now I have added the JSR223 PreProcessor with this code and it worked fine

```html
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;
Cookie newCookie;
CookieManager manager = sampler.getCookieManager();
location = vars.get("locationID_"+ vars.get("counter"))
Cookie myCookie = new Cookie("location_ID", location, google.com"/",false , 0);
manager.add(myCookie);
```