# How can I resolve active session problem in JMeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, load

Whenever I run the login/logout script, I get **You have already logged in**. How to resolve this?.

when I try to login manually. I got this popup message.
**This user is already logged in. Do you want to terminate other active session.**

So, how to handle this situation in JMETER.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RqlX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please implement the logout request and after that clean the cookie.
Follow the instruction as mentioned in
[Jmeter Clear cookies after each http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640234/jmeter-clear-cookies-after-each-http-request)

Answer (score 0):

It means that logout doesn't really logs you out, not knowing the details of your test/application it's not possible to come up with a comprehensive solution, in the meantime you can try unticking `Same user on each iteration` on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level:

[image]

or ticking `Clear cookies each iteration` box in the [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)/[HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)

[image]

If your session is being orchestrated by a custom [Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) - remove it from the [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) somehow